# Can not perform text to speech conversion in Android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

When I set `tts.speak`, using the `s` string variable it works perfectly. However, when I use the text I pass in with the function call it does not work. Both string variables are the exact same

```
private void speek(final String text){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                int isTTs = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                if(isTTs == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || isTTs == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------       ++   not working    " + isTTs);
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------       ++   " + TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA + "     " + TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------       ++   working yay    " + text);
                    tts.setPitch(0.9f);
                    tts.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
                    // if i use the variable s it works
                    String t = "Chapter 1 ...";
                    tts.speak(t, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                    // howevet this does not
                    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

TextToSpeech tts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_novel);
    // call async task
    new getPage().execute(b.getString("link"));

}


private class getPage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // call speak function and pass string to be spoken
        speek(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use log statements to check that the order of execution and the contents of your variables is what you expect.

Comment: Show `doInBackground()`'s and `b.getString()`'s code.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

the problem turned out to be the max char size that can be passed to text to speech engine is about 4000 if your string contains more than 4000 characters it will not work

```
// this will not work 
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

in order to get it working add an setOnUtteranceProgressListener and loop trough your string using onDone()

```
// working code
int char_count = 3000;
int start = 0;
int end = char_count;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "UniqueID");
tts.speak(text.substring(start, end), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, map);

tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStart(String s) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onDone(String s) {
                            start = end;
                            end+= char_count;
                            end = text.indexOf(" ", end);

                            if(end >= text.length() || end == -1){
                                end = text.length();
                            }if(start >= text.length()){
                                System.out.println("end of text");
                            }else {
                                speek();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String s) {}
                    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Without your log or the call for your function, we can't really figure out what's wrong.

My first guess would be that `text` would possibly be null (or empty if you see no NPE in your logs), etheir triggering an exception in the `speak` method or generating a blank speech. Add a null check, an empty check and see if the call has the correct signature for your `speek` function.

In this case, it would be possible that the parameter in `onPostExecute` is null.

You may also want to check [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)) to see if there are any other limitations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can try to print `text` just before calling `speak()` method to check which value was passed to the method.

We don't know content of your `doInBackground()` method, but maybe here you are passing wrong value? In your `doInBackground()` method you should return value which will be passed to `onPostExecute()`.

`urls` in `doInBackground` is Java varargs mechanism so `urls[0]` is first argument from passed to `execute()`.

When you execute:

```
new getPage().execute("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
```

in `doInBackground`:

- `urls[0]` => `"aaa"`
- `urls[1]` => `"bbb"`
- `urls[2]` => `"ccc"`

### **You can try to return first parameter** (so `urls[0]`):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // return value from parmeters
    return urls[0];
}
```